# How to check a dns txt record with php?

Tags: php, dns

I create a function to compare a txt record...

but only in my home this not work...
At my job this work...

Any tip?

Obs:

- The TXT record is created 48 hours left
- I Already clear/flush my dns cache!

  ```
  _checkTxtRecord("iocheck","imob.io","123456");  

  function _checkTxtRecord($txt_recort,$domain,$compare)
  {
      if(checkdnsrr("$txt_recort.$domain","TXT"))
      {
          $result = dns_get_record("$txt_recort.$domain",DNS_TXT);

          if(isset($result[0]["txt"]) && $result[0]["txt"]==$compare)
          {
              return true;
          }

      }
      return false;
  }
  ```

Comment: Probably your PHP version is < 5 at home and > 5 at work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I check the value of a DNS TXT record for a host?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11705946/how-can-i-check-the-value-of-a-dns-txt-record-for-a-host)

Comment: Php is 5 + on both sites , the phyton solution not solve my problem, i need to check it with php.

Comment: @davidcondrey that link is for python