# check_output error in python

Tags: python, python-2.6

I am gettin a error while running the below code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
import os
def check_output(*popenargs, **kwargs):
    process = subprocess.Popen(stdout=subprocess.PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    output, unused_err = process.communicate()
    retcode = process.poll()
    if retcode:
        cmd = kwargs.get("args")
        if cmd is None:
            cmd = popenargs[0]
        error = subprocess.CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
        error.output = output
        raise error
    return output

location = "%s/folder"%(os.environ["Home"])
subprocess.check_output(['./MyFile'])
```

**Error**

```
subprocess.check_output(['./MyFile'])
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'check_output'
```

I am working on `Python 2.6.4` .

Comment: Do you mean to use the `check_output` method that's defined?

Comment: There's a very nice way to do this, including detecting if it's necessary, given in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13160748/1194883).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use :

```
check_output(['./MyFile'])
```

You've defined your own function, it's not an attribute of `subprocess` module(for Python 2.6 and earlier).

You can also assign the function to the imported module object(but that's not necessary):

```
subprocess.check_output = check_output
location = "%s/folder" % (os.environ["Home"])
subprocess.check_output(['./MyFile'])
```

Comment: `File "DailyCheck.py", line 19, in <module>
    check_output(['./MyFile'])
  File "DailyCheck.py", line 5, in check_output
    process = subprocess.Popen(stdout=subprocess.PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 621, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1126, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory` NOt sure why I am getting this error. The file is definitelythere in the folder specified.

Comment: Try checking the value of `os.getcwd()` is correct (should be the directory that MyFile is in).

Comment: @TravisGD you are correct. I  had deleted `os.chdir(location)` by mistake , hence was getting the error.

Answer (score 7):

You *probably* just want to use `check_output`, but, just so you know, there is a method `subprocess.check_output`, but it's not defined until Python 2.7 (http://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output)

You might even want this, which defines the function in the module if it's not there (i.e. running before v2.7).

```
try: subprocess.check_output
except: subprocess.check_output = check_output
subprocess.check_output()
```

Comment: A nicer way to do that is given in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13160748/1194883).

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
from subprocess import check_output 
print(check_output(["dir", "C:\\Downloads\\file.csv"],shell=True).decode("utf8"))
```

ensure that you have `\` in your path rather than '/' and "dir" rather "ls"