# Tried to guess R's HOME but no R command in the PATH. OsX 10.6

Tags: python, r, macos, rpy2

I am trying to install rpy2 and I am facing a common issue. Unfortunately all the solution I have found are for win7

I have installed a Python 2.7 and R 2.15.
then I write on the terminal

```
easy_install rpy2
```

or, alternatively

```
pip install rpy2
```

Same result:

```
Tried to guess R's HOME but no R command in the PATH
```

What I should do?

Comment: How do you usually invoke `r` from the commmandline?

Comment: Never did it: I've installed it to use with rpy2. However I can launch it from the application folder clicking on the icon; I can get informations too: it says R.app but if I try it on the terminal it does not seems to work.

Comment: open your terminal type `echo export path=$path./bin/R/ >> ~/.bashrc` and restart your computer (replace `/bin/R` with the path to your actual R executable ... I think that will work at least (I think macs have .bashrc files)

Comment: What I should expect to see after that command? It does not do anything. Nor an error message.

Comment: @JoranBeasley -- A restart seems a little heavy handed here, don't you think?  Wouldn't you expect a simple `source ~/.bashrc` to work?

Comment: @user2988577 -- After you've run that command (presumably successfully), and if you source the file as I suggest above, then you can retry your `rpy2` install... See if it works.

Comment: Nope. Writing     source ~/.bashrc on terminal does noting (noticiable), not error, not output... And the error in the easy_install is still there.

Comment: type `tail ~/.bashrc` and make sure that command is there on the last line @mgilson yes you are right :P source should be fine ... I only run *nix from virtual boxes so I dont mess with that much

Comment: This returns
export path=./bin/R/
export path=./bin/R/./bin/R/

The error is still there.

Comment: Was this ever settled?

Comment: I wasn't able to set the issue, so I went on another avenue. But it seems I'm not the only one.

Comment: Reported to the rpy2 project as https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/issues/338/ (it seems no one did this back in 2013)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Encountering error when installing rpy2: Tried to guess R's HOME but no R command in the PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30083067/encountering-error-when-installing-rpy2-tried-to-guess-rs-home-but-no-r-comman)

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have R installed

```
brew install r
```

Then install rpy

```
pip install rpy2
```

Answer (score 2):

The rpy2 code is doing the wrong check. R might be perfectly fine, but rpy2 is using an unreliable check.

To check for `R`, the `rpy2` uses `subprocess.check_output`. However, that was introduced (AFAIK) in python 2.7.

If you're using a version of python less than 2.7 then you should update to at least 2.7.

If you must use python 2.6, then you should look at [this answer to see how to force `subprocess.check_output` into python 2.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814970/subprocess-check-output-doesnt-seem-to-exist-python-2-6-5), finally allowed you to install `rpy2`.  This is what I had to do as I was unable to update the version of python.

Download the `rpy2` code, and edit its `setup.py` and insert the code from that answer.

Comment: @dww, updating python would also resolve this. That's the easiest solution of course! But I forgot about that because I don't have control of the server that I use and can't update the system-wide python. I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

1. use `easy_install rpy2` and it works just fine.

http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.2/html/overview.html#download

Make sure you have `setuptools` installed.

If you do not know how to do that, [check this link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#windows)

You can just run ez_setup.py and let it decide for you.

2. Add C:\Program Files\R\R-2.12.1\bin\i386 (the path to R.dll) to the environment variable PATH
3. Add an environment variable R_HOME with C:\Program Files\R\R-2.12.1
4. Add an environment variable R_USER with your Windows username

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (on a Mac) and none of the solutions I found online worked. The only thing that worked for me was:

**conda update python**

**pip install rpy2**

Answer (score 0):

Installation worked for me when I did

```
pip install rpy2
```

but not when I did

```
sudo pip install rpy2
```

So in case you were using sudo and not mentioning it, this might help you. I also tried manually installing from source, which worked when I used just 'python setup.py install' for the install step, but not with sudo!

I did this on CentOS 7 with Python 2.7 and R 3.2 (as the root user). On sudo's behavior, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814970/subprocess-check-output-doesnt-seem-to-exist-python-2-6-5).