# Encountering error when installing rpy2: Tried to guess R's HOME but no R command in the PATH

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I've seen a lot of posts here and elsewhere about this error, but none of the proposed solutions appear to be relevant. I'm on [Python 2.7.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20202757/tried-to-guess-rs-home-but-no-r-command-in-the-path-osx-10-6), I have [an R executable in my path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29741232/error-tried-to-guess-rs-home-but-no-r-command-in-the-path), and I'm trying to install it on an RHEL server not on Windows.

Here's the specific error I'm seeing. Does anybody have any idea what would be causing it or how to fix it? Thanks!

```
$ pip install rpy2
Downloading/unpacking rpy2
  Downloading rpy2-2.5.6.tar.gz (165kB): 165kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_my520/rpy2/setup.py) egg_info for package rpy2
    Error: Tried to guess R's HOME but no R command in the PATH.
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Error: Tried to guess R's HOME but no R command in the PATH.
```

Comment: So, where did you install R (and what does your python session see as the $PATH)? (I think rpy2 is just an interface package but I only see rpy2 question on SO through the R side of the looking-glass.) There are many instances of R users getting confused because the "system" path is not necessarily the same path as seen from within an R session.

Comment: Yeah, I've had it installed. I'm on a HPC cluster right now and I switched to a different environment module (R 3.0.2 instead of R 3.0.0) and that fixed it. Not entirely sure why, but I'll take it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4924917/trouble-installing-rpy2-on-win7-r-2-12-python-2-5

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Download the `rpy2‑2.7.5‑cp35‑none‑win_amd64.whl` file from Christoph Gohlke's Python Extension Packages for Windows repository [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#rpy2). Using the command line, change to the download folder and run:

```
pip install rpy2‑2.5.5‑cp34‑none‑win_amd64.whl
```

This should solve the R directory issue and rpy2 should install nicely. All credit to [MattDMo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28388681/error-when-installing-rpy2-module-in-python-with-easy-install).

Comment: Just wanted to add: if cp34 didn't work, try download rpy2-2.7.8-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl  if you use python27.

Comment: I am getting a similar error on Heroku and I can't figure how to apply this on Heroku. In my case when Heroku get to the line for installing rpy2 in my requirements file, it goes to the following link for downloading rpy2 and then produces the error. https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/02/d1/074ffbbe7b4bf74c60b75d74c8e67a1e4515b0d85f85cd6540e39610754a/rpy2-2.9.5.tar.gz

Answer (score 0):

This issue available in lower version `rpy2`. After installing the ***below version***, it has been resolved.

```
rpy2==3.4.2
```